# Lazy generation of all binary sequences of a given length in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to generate all binary sequences of a given length, however I want it done lazily, so as not to overload memory.

As an example of what i want, I provide a Python code, that does exactly what I want:

```
def nextBinary(i, seq):
   b = seq[:i] + [1] + seq[i + 1:]
   yield b
   if i + 1 < len(seq):
       for nextSeq in nextBinary(i + 1, seq):
           yield nextSeq
       for nextSeq in nextBinary(i + 1, b):
           yield nextSeq


def genBinary(length):
    start = [0 for i in range(length)]
    yield start
    for seq in nextBinary(0, start):
        yield seq
```

Now the genBinary returns a generator object which I can use like this:

```
for seq in genBinary(2):
    print(seq)
# [0, 0]
# [1, 0]
# [0, 1]
# [1, 1]

for seq in genBinary(3):
    print(seq)
# [0, 0, 0]
# [1, 0, 0]
# [0, 1, 0]
# [0, 0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 0]
# [1, 0, 1]
# [1, 1, 1]
```

How would I code something equivalent in Scala? I suspect it might be somehow doable with Streams or maybe continuations.

Comment: What is the output of `genBinary(3)`? What would be the output of `genBinary(2)`?

Comment: @0__ I've added and example output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it with Streams:

```
val bss: Stream[Vector[List[Boolean]]] = 
    Vector(List.empty) #:: bss.map(bs => bs.map(true :: _) ++ bs.map(false :: _))

bss(3).mkString("\n")
//res1: String =
//List(true, true, true)
//List(true, true, false)
//List(true, false, true)
//List(true, false, false)
//List(false, true, true)
//List(false, true, false)
//List(false, false, true)
//List(false, false, false)

bss(4).mkString("\n")
//res2: String =
//List(true, true, true, true)
//List(true, true, true, false)
//List(true, true, false, true)
//List(true, true, false, false)
//List(true, false, true, true)
//List(true, false, true, false)
//List(true, false, false, true)
//List(true, false, false, false)
//List(false, true, true, true)
//List(false, true, true, false)
//List(false, true, false, true)
//List(false, true, false, false)
//List(false, false, true, true)
//List(false, false, true, false)
//List(false, false, false, true)
//List(false, false, false, false)
```

Comment: Thanks! I came up with a code that probably works (I posted it bellow), but yours is much more concise and feels like it adheres to the language more.